# Does there exist such a mollifier function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to know if there exists a (mollifier) function $\psi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

i) $\operatorname{Supp}\psi \subset B_1(0)$

ii) $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \psi(x)dx=1 $

and

iii) $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\psi'(x)|dx < \frac12 $

Comment: Don't use more than one question mark. Also, please explain what you've thought about and tried so far.

Comment: Thanks by your comments.  Really,   I want to construct a mollifier function such that the L1-norm of the first derivative  can be small enough,

Comment: The usual mollifier function don't have this property,  for instance,  look the function $\psi(x) =e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$ for $|x|\leq 1$ and $\psi(x) =0$ for $|x|>1$..

Comment: you know how to construct a $C^\infty_c$ function with arbitrary shape from the convolution of a compactly supported continuous function $f(x)$ with  $\phi(x) = e^{-1/(1-x^2)}1_{|x| < 1}$ streched (a $C^\infty_c$ approximation of the Dirac delta) ? So it reduces to looking at $C^1$ functions with propperties i) ii) iii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\psi$ satisfied properties i) and iii) listed in the question. Then $\psi(x) = 0$ for $|x|\ge 1$, and for $|x|<1$ we have
$$\psi(x) = \psi(x) - \psi(-1) = \int\limits_{-1}^{x}{\psi'(t)\text{ d}t} $$
and hence
$$|\psi(x)|\le\int\limits_{-1}^{x}{|\psi'(t)|\text{ d}t}\le\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{|\psi'(t)|\text{ d}t}<\frac{1}{2}. $$
It follows that
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{\psi(x)\text{ d}x}\le\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{|\psi(x)|\text{ d}x} = \int\limits_{-1}^{1}{|\psi(x)|\text{ d}x} < \int\limits_{-1}^{1}{\frac{1}{2}\text{ d}x} = 1. $$
Note that the last inequality is strict because $\psi$ is continuous. It follows that any $\psi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying i) and iii) cannot also satisfy ii).